# Increase width of community list popup to fit longest community name into single line

Tags: feature-request, design, communities-list

Currently some community names don't fit into single line in community popup, e.g.:

> [image]

> [image]

I suggest to increase the popup width to fit entire site name into single line, as it done for shorter names:

> [image]

This will make popup uniform and will align the distance between main/meta names and L-corner element.

The width can be increased statically for all site names (seems as easiest solution), or dynamically (depending on the current site name) for the current community.

Comment: [Proof of concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD8sS.png). (Feel free to use)

Comment: I was going to leave a comment saying that the `375px` width was used such that it could be the same width even with small viewports, but the width changes to `100%` when `@media screen and (max-width: 640px)`, so at viewport widths <= 640px the popup takes up the entire width of the screen, so it's already wider on narrower screens/windows. Thus, this is just a choice as to what looks better and if they want a static width or one which varies based on the width of the current site (which could be done completely in CSS).

Comment: I used `450px` width for my example.